# what is the difference between (NSString) *name and (NSString *) name in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

i can't understand when to use (NSString *) name and when to use (NSString) *name.
i hope someone can help me/

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses constitute a cast operator. I.e. `(NSString*) name` means, that the compiler should interpret `name` as a pointer to NSString; whereas `(NSString) *name` means that the compiler should interpret the dereferenced value (i.e., the value `name` points to) as NSString.

Comment: But since Objective-C classes are pretty much never used except as pointers, casting `*name` to `NSString` is something you should never do or see.

Comment: @KenThomases Objective-C encourage a certain **style** of using types that rarely uses class types directly. However it is not "forbidden", and it can be useful e.g., for introspection. And I prefer to give answers that explain what's going on instead of the kind "it's evil, don't do it".

Answer (score 3):

You should never need to use `(NSString)*name`. `NSString *` is a type: a pointer to an instance of `NSString`. So in a method declaration like this:

```
- (NSString *)capitalisedString: (NSString *)string
```

Each time `(NSString *)` appears it means "the thing that follows has type `NSString *`". The first one means that the return value of the method is an `NSString` instance, the second means that the type of the argument `string` is an `NSString` instance.

This discussion also applies to casting, which is when you tell a compiler to treat a variable as if it's of a particular type. Because `NSString *` is a type, you would cast like this:

```
id object = //...
NSString *myString = (NSString *)object;
```